# SwiftUI lists in Xcode Playground

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to learn SwiftUI in an Xcode playground. I was trying to make a simple list (should be easy right?) but Xcode crashes the playground while it does work in an iOS project.

This is my code:

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<5) { item in
            Text("Test")
        }
    }
}

let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
```

[image: screenshot of the error]

Comment: It is Xcode 11.3 issue. Tested & works fine with Xcode 11.2. For SwiftUI it is better to use Xcode internal Preview, which is not available in Playground. It is much more functional & convenient (and live). Just create SwiftUI based project from template.

Answer (score 0):

Can't fix the issue but anyway you definitely should checkout swift playgrounds, they are great https://www.apple.com/swift/playgrounds/ :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug in Xcode 12.5, but everything works well in Xcode 13.0 Beta

Also, In SwfitUI, you can use `PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView` instead of creating a hosting controller.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(1..<5) {
            Text("Item \($0)")
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: Swift Playground Result]

Comment: This is not working for me (Xcode 12.5) with error: "error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
"